# How to extract a substring beginning with a specific substring and ends with another specific substring?

Tags: python

I have something like that:

```
"1111Austria9999Salzburg (SZG)Vienna (VIE)1111Bosnia-Herzegovina9999Sarajevo (SJJ)1111Bulgaria9999Bourgas (BOJ)Varna (VAR)"
```

And I want to extract

```
Salzburg (SZG), Sarajevo (SJJ), Bourgas (BOJ), Varna (VAR)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind it? why didn't you capture `Vienna (VIE)`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is the python module `re`. Hint you can search for the city abbreviation with the regex which is three capital letters, how do you make it return these and the non-numerical characters before it matches this expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

sentence = "1111Austria9999Salzburg (SZG)Vienna (VIE)1111Bosnia-Herzegovina9999Sarajevo (SJJ)1111Bulgaria9999Bourgas (BOJ)Varna (VAR)"

regs = re.findall(r'[A-z]+\s\([A-Z]{3}\)', sentence)
print(regs)
```

This follows from my logic in the comments.